# What is the Firefox keyboard shortcut to open plain text url in new tab?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

There are *still* webpages which contain full urls as plain text but without the link functionality.

What I mean: www.google.com
What I don't mean: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Firefox to open that url in a new tab after selecting it with the mouse? I know I could do `CTRL + C`, `CTRL + T`, `CTRL + V`, `ENTER` but there should be something shorter. In Opera 12 you could do `CTRL + B` to accomplish what I am looking for.

Comment: It appears not. If you are already using the mouse to select, why not just use <right click> "open link in new tab"?

Comment: There's an add-on, `linkification`, which automatically makes links out of any URLs it finds in the text of a page. I use it and it works quite well, though it occasionally truncates long URLs with lots of parameters. Your two examples appear identical to me, but I understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This ADD-ON : [Search Selected Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/search-selected-shortcuts/)

`Alt + s`: Google search the selected text

`Alt + q`: Google search the selected text, but also put them in Double Quotes. E.g. you've selected, say, best creed album, then it will do a search of "best creed album"

`Alt + c`: Google search the selected text, but only search in the current site. I.e. it will do a search like, hackish site:stackoverflow.com

`Alt + i`: Google image search

There is nothing native to FF that does what you are asking at this time according to Mozilla's documentation.